# Print current index from within Angular Component?

Tags: angular, indexing, ngfor, angular-components

I currently have an Angular component being replaced for each instance of an array:

```
<app-doc-item
    *ngFor="let docFeatureEl of docFeatures; let i = index";
    [documentFeature]="docFeatureEl"
    ></app-doc-item
  >
```

I would like to access the index each index (**i**) and print that value from within the component:

My child component looks as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="list-item" (click)="onSelected()">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ docFeature?.string }}</h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

ideally, the goal is to pass that index as a parameter for the onSelected() to perform actions on that particular instance,

unfortunately whenever I try to access **i** Angular tells me **property 'i' does not exist on type**

How do I access this index produced from within the component?

Cheers!

Comment: I am not well versed in angularJS, but in modern angular I would pass that index as an input. Maybe you could try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add index as an input on app-doc-item component

```
<app-doc-item
    *ngFor="let docFeatureEl of docFeatures; let i = index";
    [documentFeature]="docFeatureEl"
    [index]="i">
</app-doc-item>
```

And use it in your onSelected

```
<a href="#" class="list-item" (click)="onSelected(index)">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ docFeature?.string }}</h4>
  </div>
</a>
```